# Curl - POST request using JSON with query parameter

Tags: json, http, curl, post

I have a URL https://mylink/apply?data= for a server which accepts the **data** variable as valid JSON of following properties:-

- name: String with your name (required)
- email: String with your email address (required)
- urls: Array of strings with links
- comment: String with any comment/request you might have (optional)

My JSON file "data.json" is the following:

```
{
    "data":
    {
        "name": "Rogers Bell",
        "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "urls":["https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067241/imran", "https://github.com/i4ali"],
        "comment":"none"
    }
}
```

When I use the following CURL command to send a POST request, I get error code **400 Bad Request** with a message from the server **Error: no data passed.** indicating something wrong with my JSON format or command. Not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
curl -v -i -X POST -d @data.json https://mylink/apply?data= -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k
```

I am using Windows 7 if that matters

Comment: I suggest you either use GET and send everything in the query, or use POST and put the entire query in the body.
But I'd need the API documentation to give you a definite answer...

Comment: My guess - you need to specify header application/json

Comment: @Konrads I am doing that already with the -H "Content-Type: application/json" in the CURL command

Comment: When JSON file content is sent by `curl`, all carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out -- it would still be a valid JSON but server may not be able to recognize. Can you send the same content (with carriage returns and newlines) through Postman and check again? Is there any API document?

Comment: @shaochuancs I tried postman putting the json under body->raw(json) format but I get the same error code '400 Bad Request' and a message 'Error: no data passed'. Unfortunately API is not free to look at

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API is pretty weird. But if you have to read JSON file and POST its content to server as URL parameter, you can `cat` the file, encode it and send it in `curl`. Here is an example:

```
curl -G -X POST https://requestb.in/1n88lah1 --data-urlencode data="$(cat input.json)"
```

The `input.json` would look like:

```
{
    "name": "Rogers Bell",
    "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "urls":["https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067241/imran", "https://github.com/i4ali"],
    "comment":"none"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Postman I was able to send this POST request with the following complete URL. Got a **200 OK** response

```
https://mylink/apply?data={
    "name": "Rogers Bell",
    "email": "xxxx@gmail.com",
    "urls":["https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067241/imran", "https://github.com/i4ali"],
    "comment":"none"
}
```

Comment: Are you sending JSON data through URL parameter? The API is so weird...

Comment: yes, exactly. I was also surprised this worked since my understanding was you cant do a POST request with JSON data through query strings

Comment: Actually, you can send POST request with parameter in URL. However, normally this is not the way to send data.